# Bluemix IoT Foundation Environment Stopped Working

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

I noticed this afternoon that my Bluemix IoT Application was in the 'Unknown' state. When I mined into the app to see what the problem could be, I got the following pop-up:

[App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5yOq.png)

I haven't made any changes to my NodeRED flows in months, and if I spin up a new IOT Foundation app, it starts just fine.

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

A recent update to the underlying application stack has caused an incompatibility with older versions of the IoTF boilerplate.

The fix is to edit your application's package.json file and remove the 'mqlight' entry under the dependencies section. New instances of the boilerplate already have this entry removed - hence why they work.

Comment: Here is an example of the line that needs to be removed from your package.json file: 
 
        "mqlight":"0.1.x",

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check the bluemix server status at https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

There were some issues reported around scheduled maintenance. There are also buildpack updates scheduled.

Comment: That is in internal link that must not be shared. The public link is https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Comment: @knolleary: Thank you for sharing this link. It shows a blank page though. Do you know any alternative links that may give an outlook on the availability of the bluemix server?